# ruby mixing and inheritance injection

Tags: ruby, inheritance, callback, metaprogramming, mixins

I need to inject a callbacks in every child class of a Parent class. So, method with callbacks must be called first, and all present chain later:

it is possible to achive thought alias_method (or alias_method_chain):

```
module ChildMod1
  def save
    puts "save ChildMod1"
    super
  end
end

module ChildMod2
  def save
    puts "save ChildMod2"
    super
  end
end

class Parent
  def save
    puts "save Parent"
  end
end
class Child < Parent
  include ChildMod1
  include ChildMod2

  def save
    puts "save Child"
    super
  end

  alias_method :old_save, :save
  module_eval <<-R
      def save
        puts "save Callback"
        old_save
      end
    R
end
c = Child.new
c.save
```

output

```
save Callback
save Child
save ChildMod2
save ChildMod1
save Parent
```

but is it possible to achieve this via inheritance? like in ChildMod1 or ChildMod2. I whant to execute a code inside a module space to get all benefits from inheritance

```
module ChildMod1
  def save
    puts "save ChildMod1"
    super
  end
end

module ChildMod2
  def save
    puts "save ChildMod2"
    super
  end
end

class Parent
  def save
    puts "save Parent"
  end
end
class Child < Parent
  include ChildMod1
  include ChildMod2

  def save
    puts "save Child"
    super
  end

  module_eval <<-R
      def save
        puts "save Callback"
        super
      end
    R

end

c = Child.new
c.save
```

Output

```
save Callback
save ChildMod2
save ChildMod1
save Parent
```

as you see, it just overwrite Child

**UPDATE**
wdebeaum solution is good, but what if i need to create a lot of methods dynamically thought module_eval or analog and redefine them inside a class? I cannot create a separate module for them.

```
class TestEval
  def redefine_me
    puts "Test method"
    super # I expect that it will call Eval method, but module_eval just overwrite it
  end

  module_eval <<-R
      def redefine_me
        puts "Eval method"
      end
    R
end
```

**UPDATE2**
using a singleton class i'll got wrong chain Eval => Test instead of Test => Eval

```
class TestEval
  def initialize
    class << self
      def redefine_me
        puts "Eval method"
        super
      end
    end
  end
  def redefine_me
    puts "Test method"
  end
end

TestEval.new.redefine_me
```

Let assume, that I have a class method "field", that add some instance methods to a Datastream (for ex it'll add setter and getter methods) and I whant to redefine one of this methods, like this:

```
class Datastream 
  field :name 
  def name=(value) 
    puts "redefined!"
    super
  end 
end
```

Comment: BTW i created a gem after this question https://github.com/AlexParamonov/inheritance_module_eval
just forgot to add it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the callback method in its own module, and rewrite the Parent's initialize method to `extend` that module (using `alias_method` if necessary). This will put the callback method before the Child's method, by linking it to each Child instance's singleton class. Just remove the `module_eval` part from your second code example, and add this before `c = Child.new`:

```
module Callback
  def save
    puts "save Callback"
    super
  end
end

class Parent
  alias_method :old_initialize, :initialize
  def initialize
    old_initialize
    extend Callback
  end
end
```

Output:

```
save Callback
save Child
save ChildMod2
save ChildMod1
save Parent
```

Comment: nice. I've vote you up. Your solution is good, but what if i need to create a lot of methods dynamically thought module_eval or analog and redefine them inside a class? I cannot create a separate module for them. I'll update a post with new example soon.

Comment: Why can't you make a separate module? If you just want to create methods dynamically, you could use `Module.new` to dynamically create the module, and then use `module_eval` on that module as you have been doing. If you really can't make new modules at all, you could try adding methods to each instance's singleton class instead of extending a module. But to me that seems like extra work for little reason.

Comment: regarding my question about callbacks you gave a correct solution. Question in Update2 section is very similar, can you suggest something for it?

Comment: Wait, I thought you wanted the dynamically added method to be called first? Why do you say "Eval => Test" is wrong in that example?

Comment: yes.. actually i was looking for something, that will allow me to create methods as they are in a module. Because i had 2 problems: how to define callbacks (and you gave brilliant answer for that) and how to use module_eval to create inheritance structure, like "include Module" does to support things, like in UPDATE2